# How to route through intermediate VPN gateway?

Tags: vpn, routing

Hello I'm not really system administrator nor network skilled so go easy on me.

I'm trying to route through VPN on windows 7. I did add

```
route -p ADD 10.165.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.124.16.2 METRIC 1
```

And it worked ok. I can se in my

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.4    266
      10.124.16.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.106     20
      10.124.23.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.106     20
       10.165.0.0      255.255.0.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.106     20
```

So it automatically recognized it has to go first through VPN gateway which is 192.168.3.1

When I did same for another address:

```
route -p ADD 10.139.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.124.16.2 METRIC 1
```

I'm getting active routes:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1      192.168.0.4    266
      10.124.16.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.106     20
      10.124.23.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.106     20
       10.139.0.0      255.255.0.0      10.124.16.2    192.168.3.106     21
       10.165.0.0      255.255.0.0      192.168.3.1    192.168.3.106     20
```

I think it is not correct because it can not reach "10.124.16.2" directly. On the other hand I expect that active routes are combined with priority from top-down. Wich means that if 2nd line is telling how to route 10.124.16.0 it still may work, right?

Anyway I tried also set explicitly VPN interface:

```
Interface List
 17...44 45 53 54 4f 53 ......Kerio Virtual Network Adapter
```

using:

```
route -p ADD 10.139.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.124.16.2 METRIC 1 IF 17
```

I tried to restart machine, omit `-p`, do `route delete 10.139.0.0`, try to flush some cashes with command `netsh interface ip delete destinationcache` but nothing helped. I can not ping there and `tracert` does not tell me any ip - just:

```
Tracing route to 10.139.16.167 over a maximum of 30 hops
  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Our IT guy told me that my routing is correct and my windows must have remember something wrong in some cache. He told me that he has same routing and works for him.

Any idea what can be wrong??? I'm really lost and clue less and desperate because I need to get there...

Answer (score 0):

So problem solved - sometimes if your IT tells you that problem is on your site - you just need to tell them: no problem is on your side. I was missing some right in vpn server side...

Anyway good tricks we come up:
You can try to set both gateway and make windows to solve it - like this:

```
Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      10.139.0.0      255.255.0.0      192.168.3.1       1
      10.139.0.0      255.255.0.0      10.124.16.2       1
```

It's probably not correct but in desperate case you may try.

Another best thing to do if you are (unfortunately) on windows is to install `wireshark`. Spy on desired interface and check if ping packet is sent on that interface. If so just go to your IT and let them solve it ;)

On linux you can directly ask: `/sbin/ip route get 10.139.16.167`

And last thing is to re-install your SVN client. After all the fact that it goes to your virtual IP does not meant that VPN client is working and forwarding it through your real interface (and it's hard to spy this as it is encrypted channel)